# Java stream API. Find field of an object matching predicate in one line. Return some default value if not exists

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

For example, we have a simple class with some fields. Let's assume, we have fields called 'name' and 'id'. And I want to get name of an object with specified id and return some defaultName, if there is no such object:

```
private List<MyObject> myObjects;
public String findFieldById(int id) {
    MyObject matchingObj = myObjects.stream()
                    .filter(m -> m.getId() == id)
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);

    return (matchingObj == null) ? "defaultName" : matchingObj.getName();
}
```

My question is how can I easily make this check on null **in a stream in one line**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can perform this type of operation in one pipeline by mapping to `MyObject::getName` after `findFirst` otherwise provide a default value via `orElse`.

```
return myObjects.stream()
         .filter(m -> m.getId() == id)
         .findFirst()
         .map(MyObject::getName)
         .orElse("defaultName");
```

Comment: @TorstenOjaperv well one can make it into one line but it wouldn't be as readable. I assume the OP meant _one pipeline_ instead of _one line_ hence I've also mentioned this in the answer "You can perform this type of operation in **one pipeline**..."

Comment: @TorstenOjaperv You always want to split up stream operations into multiple lines, otherwise its a mess to read and not clearer that actually writing it out (without streams).

Comment: Keep in mind that this will return `"defaultName"` when `myObject.getName()` yields `null`

Comment: @Lino this can be fixed by using `.map(MyObject::getName) .findFirst() .orElse("defaultName")` instead. Due to the lazy nature of streams, this will still only invoke `getName` on the first matching element, if there is one, but now, there will be a `NullPointerException`, if that call to `getName()` returned `null`. This differs from your solution which would just return the `null`, but to me, a method supposed to provide a `"defaultName"` if there is no match does not seem to be supposed to return `null` in any case.

Comment: @Holger I completely agree with you, it makes more sense to always return a non `null` value. This case could also be handled by using an intermediate `Optional` and then only return the `"defaultName"` wrapped inside an `Optional` if the prior isn't present. The signature of the method would then change to return an `Optional<String>` leaving the caller to decide what he wants to do if the name is not available, but an object was found

Answer (score 3):

You are not forced to use streams, a simple java for-loop with an if-statement will do the trick too:

```
public String findFieldById(int id) {
    // iterate over all objects
    for(MyObject myObject : myObjects){
        // if an object's id matches the given parameter
        if(myObject.getId() == id){
            // we will return its name
            return myObject.getName();
        }
    }
    // if nothing was found we will return the default
    return "defaultName";
}
```